# How to install pdflib on WAMP Server

Tags: php, pdf, wampserver, pdflib

I want to install pdflib on my wampserver2.

I have [downloaded pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/download/) and I've set the following line:

```
extension=php_pdflib.dll
```

in my `php.ini` file, but I'm still getting a `Call to undefined function pdf_new()` error.

Comment: have you restarted the wamp server? Is there anything on the apache error logs?

Comment: yes i have restarted wamp server

Answer (score 3):

You must copy the `libpdf_php.dll` to the extension directory of your php installation (check for `extension_dir` in your `phpinfo()` output).

Also take care to use the version of PDFlib that matches your php version and compiler (multiple versions are included in the download you mentioned).

Then add `extension=libpdf_php.dll` to the `php.ini` (you can also find it's location listed in the phpinfo() output, just look for `php.ini`).

Restart your webserver and check if you have a "PDF" entry in your `phpinfo()` and if so, congratulations!

If you want more detailed information about PDFlib and it's use in php , be sure to check out the [online php howto](http://www.pdflib.com/developer/technical-documentation/pdflib-in-php-howto/)(a pdf link, of course) and also consult the documentation included in your download package.

Answer (score 1):

Here are what you should do in order to install **phppdf** library:

**1 . download**: download the package which matches your php version from [here](http://pecl.php.net/package/pdflib) (check the php version using phpinfo() command).

The package shall contain the following files,

```
php_pdflib.dll  //php extension
php_pdflib.pdb  //don't know what it does!
pdflib.dll      //actual pdf library
```

**2 . copy**: copy **php_pdflib.dll** into the extensions directory (again find the extension directory using phpinfo() command **"extension_dir"**). also copy **php_pdflib.pdb** and **pdflib.dll** into the main php directory (**right next to the php.exe**)

**3 . config**: add the extension to php.ini. just remember wamp uses another version of php.ini at **apache/bin/php.ini**, So make sure you're making changes on the right file. (again find the php.ini's path using phpinfo() command, **Loaded Configuration File**). Add the following line:

```
extension=php_pdflib.dll
```

Comment: Unfortunately that link no longer provides binary packages. They only contain source code.

Comment: There is no dll file available. only .c files. How to deploy?? Can anyone help?

Comment: @EscalinNancy It's no longer available, Try **tFPDF** instead. It's a lot easier to use.