# How to generate pdf document using wamp

Tags: php, pdf, wamp

Please how do I get my wamp server to generate pdf documents, I downloaded pdflib but it's in tar format. I'm using wamp 2.1 so all it's modules are dll files. Please what do I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371262/how-to-install-pdflib-on-wampserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this up: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php. A PECL extension, learn how to install it from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

- [How to install pdflib on WAMP Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371262/how-to-install-pdflib-on-wampserver)
  is another question that may be what exactly you need.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560583/which-is-the-best-pdf-library-for-php

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php). A very vast library and easy to use. It also provides online support in case you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Either you can use [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) or [fpdf](http://fpdf.org). Both has good documentation with nice pdf output.